# Chosen select not calling a function on ng-click

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I'm working with a chosen select, i added a function call when the event ng-click happens, but it's not doing anything, when i make the call to the same function in a button it works, why is this?

ng-change doesn't work either, even worse, it eats my options and leaves only the first one.

my select code:

```
<select ng-model="ind_oferta"  multiple class="control-group chosen-select" chosen >
              <optgroup label="Oferta">
                 <option value=""> </option>
                 <option ng-click="aplicarFiltro()" ng-repeat="menuOpcion in menu[0].opciones.oferta" value={{menuOpcion.id}}>
                  {{menuOpcion.tipo}}</option>
              </optgroup>
        </select>
```

the function is very simple, it's just a javascript alert

```
$scope.aplicarFiltro = function(){ 

        alert("hello");

    }
```

and i think is not worth put the button code, that one works so...

**EDIT:** i changed the select code to this, still not making the call to the function, help!

```
<select multiple class="control-group chosen-select" chosen style="width:250px;"
                ng-model="ind_oferta" ng-click="aplicarFiltro();"
                ng-options="menuOpcion.id as menuOpcion.tipo for menuOpcion in menu[0].opciones.oferta">
                <option>--</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Are you using Chosen JQuery directly or with a directive for Angular (https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen)?

Comment: with a directive, the select itself is fine, i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive together with `ng-model` (you can still add a single `<option>` as the default value). It would probably look something like this:

```
<select ng-options="menuOpcion.tipo for menuOpcion in menu[0].opciones.oferta" 
        ng-model="selected" 
        ng-change="aplicarFiltro()" chosen multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

There is a lot of customization options, so it is best if you check out the documentation.

To get the option which was removed by the user you could do something like this in your controller:

```
var previousSelection = [];
$scope.changedSelection = function () {
  // Check if the current selection contains every element of the previous selection
  for (var i = 0; i < previousSelection.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.selectModel.indexOf(previousSelection[i]) == -1) {
      // previousSelection[i] was deselected        
    }
  }
  // Set the previous selection to the current selection
  previousSelection = $scope.selectModel;
}
```

Comment: That is probably because `menuOpcion` itself is an object and not a string. I edited the expression inside the `ng-options`, can you try it out again?

Comment: yeah, now it fills with the text, but the function still not working, any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I added `ng-change` as well. This function will be called whenever your selection changes. Depending on how complex your filter is though, you might be able to just bind the `selected` property directly to your filter.

Comment: ok, that will do it, just one last detail, how i can track if an option was removed by the user?